# Explicitly list all phpmyadmin databases without cascading by name prefixes?

Tags: phpmyadmin

Please see the attached screenshot. We have a team of data analysts who each manage hundreds of different databases and it's a regular task to **find** a specific database by its **name**.

However the way phpMyAdmin lists the databases by name prefixes that you must click it to list the databases is very annoying as you can't search a specific database by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.

Search via SQL with `SHOW DATABASES LIKE '%xxxx%'` is also not so friendly in terms of efficiency. Not to mention the query results give no link to the database index page. One still have to manually copy the name and paste it in the URL.

Tried googling but nothing useful came up as it seems to be a rather rare scenario to manage hundreds of databases per user in phpMyAdmin.

Is there any way to make phpMyAdmin to display all databases and their names verbally and literally without the prefix cascading list so we can simply search a database name by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. Just use these in the config.inc.php:

```
/* Disable database grouping in navigation */
$cfg['ShowDatabasesNavigationAsTree'] = false;
$cfg['NavigationTreeEnableGrouping'] = false;

/* Disable paging of databases with a large number */
$cfg['FirstLevelNavigationItems'] = 2000;
```

Now all database names are in a literal list without any cascading or paging and you can search them by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.